# pset4 cs50 speller -trie valgrind causing cs50 IDE to shut down

Tags: c, cs50, trie

I am working on cs50 pset4 speller using trie. When unloading the dictionary although the dictionary is unloaded (it completes without segfault), I can not run valgrind().

Although valgrind() works when i give a small dictionary, but when I use the default large dictionary, valgrind() just stops working and the message of no connection pops up and I am returned to the dashboard. So I tried running check50 with the log flag, and this message popped up:

```
checking for valgrind errors... 
        Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 77)
        Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 152)
        Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 144)
        Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 114)
        Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 105)
        Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 166)
        32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
```

I am aware of the last line and trying to fix it, but what are these other lines. I am unloading by the following code.

```
bool func_unload(node *unloader)
{
    node *temp = unloader;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        temp = unloader;
        if(unloader -> children[i] != NULL)
        {
            func_unload(unloader -> children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(unloader);
    unloader = temp;
    return true;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    func_unload(root);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is giving you the line numbers. And only you know what is in there.

Comment: can valgrind() cause the IDE to shut down????

Comment: IDE can be buggy. You don't even specify what kind of IDE.

Comment: i am using cs50 ide

Comment: They have a special IDE now? Cool. This course is doing everything to make it disconnected from the real-world programming as much as possible... I believe there is a dedicated SE site for CS50 somewhere. Here it is https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ , and I saw questions about this exercise are there